# search for a string and delete duplicates and add new line to second and last line of a text using bash

Tags: xml, bash, annotations

I am looking to search for a specific text/string and delete the duplicates and then add a specific text to the second and the last line of the file using bash

```
For eg: I have this format:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<annotation type="face">
    <object id="0">
        <arg name="pos_x" value="822"/>
        <arg name="pos_y" value="245"/>
        <arg name="pose" value="front"/>
        <arg name="size_x" value="63"/>
        <arg name="size_y" value="77"/>
        <arg name="score" value="112"/>
    </object>   
</annotation>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<annotation type="track">
    <object id="0">
        <arg name="pos_x" value="682"/>
        <arg name="pos_y" value="247"/>
        <arg name="pose" value="front"/>
        <arg name="size_x" value="121"/>
        <arg name="size_y" value="121"/>
        <arg name="score" value="178"/>
    </object>
    <object id="1">
        <arg name="pos_x" value="786"/>
        <arg name="pos_y" value="243"/>
        <arg name="pose" value="front"/>
        <arg name="size_x" value="128"/>
        <arg name="size_y" value="128"/>
        <arg name="score" value="161"/>
    </object>   
</annotation>

and i need this format
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<frame>
<annotation type="face">
    <object id="0">
        <arg name="pos_x" value="822"/>
        <arg name="pos_y" value="245"/>
        <arg name="pose" value="front"/>
        <arg name="size_x" value="63"/>
        <arg name="size_y" value="77"/>
        <arg name="score" value="112"/>
    </object>   
</annotation>
<annotation type="track">
    <object id="0">
        <arg name="pos_x" value="682"/>
        <arg name="pos_y" value="247"/>
        <arg name="pose" value="front"/>
        <arg name="size_x" value="121"/>
        <arg name="size_y" value="121"/>
        <arg name="score" value="178"/>
    </object>
    <object id="1">
        <arg name="pos_x" value="786"/>
        <arg name="pos_y" value="243"/>
        <arg name="pose" value="front"/>
        <arg name="size_x" value="128"/>
        <arg name="size_y" value="128"/>
        <arg name="score" value="161"/>
    </object>   
</annotation>
</frame>
```

So here the changes are keeping the first line and deleting the duplicated and then adding tag frame to 2nd line and /frame to last line

Comment: are you looking to get rid of any duplicate tags, or duplicates within the same branch, or just duplicate processing instructions? Also are you going to use an XML parser for any of it or just parse it solely using minimalistic tools?

Comment: It is unclear what you really want to do. Can you show us an example of an output where some thing were already replaced/removed? Also, better use an XML parser instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you want to delete the second occurrence of `<?xml ... ?>` and wrap everything in the `<frame>` tag using only command line tools. This can all be done with a sed one-liner

```
sed '0,/<?xml.*>/! s/<?xml.*>//g' -e '2i <frame>' -e '$a </frame>'
```

The first expression deletes all `<?xml ... ?>` tags excluding the first one, the second expression inserts `<frame>` at line 2, and the third expression appends `</frame>` at the end.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Here the adding the <frame> and </frame> tags works but the deletion of duplicates of <?xml*> is not working. any changes you recommend?

Comment: I'm not sure. It worked for me on the example you gave. Did you use <?xml.*> and not <?xml*>?

Comment: actually this works on a file basis i.e one file at a time and process it. But my case is i am storing the output of console to file and the format is above mentioned and i try to do post processing on the file as you mentioned. So in real time when i do it using script the <frame> and </frame> is added respectively but the <?xml....> tag is being deleted including first line.

Something like this:
# Provide xml file
 'rm -f temp.xml
 SkipToDelimiter temp.xml
 cat temp.xml | sed -e '0,/<?xml.*>/! s/<?xml.*>//g' -e '2i <frame number="'$current_frame'">' -e '$a </frame>' > $xml'

Comment: If you know that the first <?xml?> tag will be on the first line, then this may work for you: sed -e '2,${s/<?xml.*>//g' -e '2i <frame>' -e '$a </frame>'. Otherwise, I don't know how to help since I can't reproduce the problem.